# Z3 maxsat smtlib 2.0

Tags: z3

Is there a way to do maxsat with the c++ api using the smtlib2.0 instances.
Namely, how to make the function get_soft_constraints to work with the smtlib2.0 instances?

Answer (score 1):

No, the `maxsat` example was implemented before SMT 2.0 was introduced. 
The example can be modified to read SMT 2.0 files. The basic idea is to use the SMT 2.0 parser instead of the SMT 1.0, and devise some mechanism to identify soft constraints.